# Create View by select * from exec(MySP)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I created Pivot Table with dynamic number of columns however to achieve that I needed to create a string Query and run it using Exec('MyStringQuery'), that was the only way I could get the result I wanted.

Now I want to create a View using my Pivot table. Since in View I cannot run Exec(myQry)

I thought to create a function and run my query there and then use it in my View but I cannot create a table variable to put the result in there, because number of my columns my vary each time I run the query.

How can I achieve this?

```
create View myView
as
select * from exec(MySP)
```

It gives me an error when I try to run it.

Would appreciate your input very much.

Comment: Why does this need to be a view?

Comment: You can not have a dynamic number of columns in a view. So even if there where some workaround on executing a SP in a view, it would not work anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found an answer to my question.
I created a Store procedure and used OpenRowset and created my view

```
Create MyView

AS

SELECT  *FROM 

  OPENROWSET( 'SQLNCLI',
                    'Server=SERVERNAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
                    'SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NOCOUNT ON; exec DatabaseName.dbo.MySP @A=1,@B=2')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a view, sorry. You can't pass parameters to a view, nor can you use dynamic SQL in a view. You also can't execute dynamic SQL in a function, so it won't work there. You'll need to call a stored procedure to do this I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I created SP now what i need is use that SP in my view.

Comment: You can't call a stored procedure from a view. I've asked before but I'll ask again - why does this need to be a view?

Comment: I'm sorry didn't see your question! Well.,. working on a VSTO project That I need to show some data in my excel sheet from DB which only accept tables or views. I also know that it is not possible but thought someone might have a different approach to this